# Create 'safe' JavaScript for use on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/052Ja.png (Can't post image because I'm a new user)

Age old question; is there any way to make a piece of JavaScript safe to use on Internet Explorer without having the security warning popup box. The JavaScript I'm using is simply a drop-down sub-menu that appears when you hover over a link.

If it's something to do with the way the JavaScript is coded, I can link if needed.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as far as you can't manipulate the browser settings of your client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your problem is caused by testing pages from your local disk (and not through some really esoteric scripting) either:

- Run a web server and test your pages on that
- Give your pages [the mark of the web](http://www.helpstuff.com/motw.html)

The point being to run them in a security context that allows scripts to execute.

Comment: Many thanks. Running via a WAMP server and adding the Mark of the web fixed the issue.